# why i cannot find some html content in the code

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a html5 game and want to change some of it's content I want to find out where is that score and that Chinese character in the source code

i tried to read code line by line in index.html and index.js and main.js but not found that

[Here is the Image of that Chinese  character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynw9u.jpg)

here is the source code :

https://github.com/iamkun/tower_game

how can i find that

Comment: Maybe,  Already, the index.js file is the main.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it on this file: https://github.com/iamkun/tower_game/blob/master/src/animateFuncs.js

line 21